# Custom protocol in Chrome not working as expected

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, registry, protocols

My register file looks like this (Exoscape.reg):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher]
"URL Protocol"="\"\""

@="\"URL:ExoScape-Launcher Protocol\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher\DefaultIcon]
@="\"Launcher.jar,1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\ExoScape\\Launcher.jar\" \"%1\""
```

My files are inside the correct location, when I try to test this in CMD I get no error but nothing launches:

```
"C:\Program Files\ExoScape\Launcher.jar" "ExoScape-Launcher:Launcher.jar"
```

My `HREF` tag looks like this in my site, when clicked, I get the Open Launcher prompt which when pressed, launches nothing:

```
<a href="ExoScape-Launcher:Launcher.jar">Play Now</a>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `ExoScape-Launcher:\\Launcher.jar` Or `ExoScape-Launcher:\\\Launcher.jar` ?

Comment: Neither working @aynber

Answer (score 0):

If you'd have exported any existing protocol definition (i.e. `\HKCR\http\` or `\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\http\` instead of `\HKCU\*`) and compared that to your one then you'd have noticed that it should be at least `"URL Protocol"=""` (unset, not empty text). Also the empty line might irritate REGEDIT to properly import your file.

So, export that, modify it to your needs, and try again. And why have you omitted the path for DefaultIcon?

Comment: How should it look then, I followed that directly from a tutorial

Comment: "A tutorial"? You neither mentioned that, nor linked to it. So far I can only say it's wrong.

Comment: I mean, its directly from the msdn docs to use your own class name, Classes\http would be http:$1 where $1 is the query, I want exoscape-launcher:$1 so ur answer makes no sense either? Also, URL Protocol should be empty, it is only a declaration

Comment: You don't understand: open REGEDIT, navigate to that `http` key, then export all that, then check that file (compare against what you quoted), then modify it to your needs. And `"\"\""` doesn't equal `""`, hence it's wrong. "msdn docs" is too broad - link to the actual page.