# Registering an application to a URL

Tags: php, google-chrome, registry, protocols, custom-protocol

I have been following the [msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) to simulate a URL opening an application,  but in my case, a java application. I created a registry file which looks like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher]
"URL Protocol"="\"\""
@="\"ExoScape Launcher\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\exoscape-launcher\shell\open\command]
@="java -jar \"C:\\Program Files\\ExoScape\\Launcher.jar\""
```

I manually installed this registry entry by double clicking it. I checked all files where named correctly and inside the correct directory.

I then created my URL:

```
<a href='exoscape-launcher:'>Play</a>
```

Which when clicked gives me this output:

[image: Output]

However, when I press open, my application is not launched and nothing happens.

My expected output is [RS3](http://www.runescape.com/game)'s approach to launching the game. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom protocol in Chrome not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810591/custom-protocol-in-chrome-not-working-as-expected)